# How to create bounds of a android polyline in order to fit the screen?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an arraylist of LatLng coordinates. And I draw a polyline based on that coordinates list. How can I fit that polyline drawing into my screen? Is LatLngBounds.Builder the correct solution for that? If it is how can I use it?

Answer (score 12):

You can try something like this:

```
private void moveToBounds(Polyline p){

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(int i = 0; i < p.getPoints().size();i++){
        builder.include(p.getPoints().get(i));
    }

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels

    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have do some improvements to the answer:
The answer from Melo ist to slow

```
private void moveToBounds(Polyline p)
{

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    List<LatLng> arr = p.getPoints();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size();i++){
        builder.include(arr.get(i));
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    int padding = 40; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the markers and the polyline points.

```
    public void setMapMarkersBounds(List<Marker> markers, Polyline polyline) {
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder;
    float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding = (int) (40 * scale + 0.5f);
    builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (Marker marker : markers) {
        builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < polyline.getPoints().size(); i++){
        builder.include(polyline.getPoints().get(i));
    }

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu, 400, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void moveToBounds(Polyline polyline, int padding){

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        for(LatLng latLng : polyline.getPoints()){
            builder.include(latLng);
        }

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), padding));
}
```